# visual studio 2019...newline after leading comma

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, indentation, autoformatting

I've this notice an annoying behavior from Visual Studio (*possibly the Intellisense*) and am wondering if anyone knows how to disable it.

Here's what I am trying to do

```
TheoryData<string> TestData = new ()
{
    { 'hello' }
  , { "world" }
};
```

Whenever I copy **, { "world" }** and paste, Visual Studio does this:

```
,
{ "world" }
```

Then I have to go in to remove the newline and the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:**

Uncheck "**Automatically format on paste**" option in **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Formatting** > **General** will work, and further, consider unchecking "**Automatically format block on }**".

**Analyzing:**

Focus on this two options(in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > General):

1). Automatically format on paste

2). Automatically format block on }

Just uncheck `Automatically format on paste` option will make your issue("whenever I copy XXXX and **paste**, XXXXX") resolved.

But under this circumstance, if you don't copy -> paste, instead, manually type "," and then "{}", the issue will appear again. I mean, you will see that the new brace automatically format in a new line.

To resolve this, there is another option => `Automatically format block on }`, uncheck this option will avoid auto complete feature which formats open brace to a new line.

But you need to consider whether you prefer this, as normally "Automatically format block on }" is useful, and "Automatically format on paste" is also useful.